# As the emotional strain.... or As emotional strain

Tags: articles

which is correct out of two, do I use the or not in-front of emotional in sentence that starts with As

As the emotional strain between us was..
As emotional strain between us was..

Answer (score 1):

I think they're both interchangeable, you can use it if you want to.

I tend to use

> As the emotional strain...

Although

> As emotional strain...

Isn't wrong, and could be used just as easily.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the version with the article, *as **the** emotional strain was...* because we are not discussing emotional strain in general, we're discussing a particular, specific strain: the one that is between us.  Therefore, the definite article is more appropriate, because that's how we refer to a specific, known thing.

Reference: [How to Use Articles (a/an/the)](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/540/01/)